# Modbus cant read data from epever tracer 1210a to raspberry

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

i want to make a monitoring program for tracer

i use rs485 usb converter to connect epever tracer1210a to raspberry pi 3 model b

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

client = ModbusClient(method = 'rtu', port = '/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate = 115200)
client.connect()
print( client)
result = client.read_input_registers(0x3100,6,unit=1)
print (result)

solarVoltage = float(result.registers[0] /100.0)
solarCurrent = float(result.registers[1] /100.0)
batteryVoltage = float(result.registers[4] /100.0)
chargeCurrent = float(result.registers[5] /100.0)

print("solar voltage : ",solarVoltage)
print("solar current : ",solarCurrent)
print("battery volatage : ",batteryVoltage)
print("charge current : ",chargeCurrent)
client.close()
```

and i get error like this:

ModbusSerialClient(rtu baud[115200])
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yutub.py", line 9, in 
    solarVoltage = float(result.registers[0] /100.0)
AttributeError: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'

please help me to fix this problem

Comment: This is quite likely a hardware issue. Can you please add the brand and model of your RS485-to-USB converter? If you have a link to the manual and/or other info add it too.

Comment: this is the converter that I use https://www.tokopedia.com/snapshot_product?order_id=339813809&dtl_id=537423544. I've tried it on software called "solar station monitor" on windows, and it works fine. 
all data from mppt is displayed there correctly. 
I thought my converter cable had no problems.

Comment: Then I guess it should work with pymodbus right away. Try changing to `unit=0`, according to the manual the default address is 0x00.

Comment: still can't when i changing unit and default address. this is a address list from my tracer http://www.solar-elektro.cz/data/dokumenty/1733_modbus_protocol.pdf . is there a mistake in entering the address?

Comment: I googled the name you posted and I found a manual indicating default ID zero... Maybe you can check with the settings of your other software? The documentation is not that great. They say, for instance, that registers are in decimal and then they write Hex values!

Comment: Wait, something I missed! If your port is USB your device name should be `/dev/ttyUSB0` or any other index.

Comment: my problem has been solved. thank you for helping me in solving my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had faced the same problem.

Follow the below steps to fix the issue:

1. git clone https://github.com/kasbert/epsolar-tracer/tree/master/xr_usb_serial_common-1a
2. Follow the installation steps from Readme.

You might face problem when you execute `make`. In such case do `sudo apt-get install linux-headers`.

- Check that the USB UART is detected by the system

  `lsusb`
- Check that the CDC-ACM driver was not installed for the Exar USB UART

  `ls /dev/tty*`

  To remove the CDC-ACM driver and install the driver:

  `sudo rmmod cdc-acm`

  `sudo modprobe -r usbserial`

  `sudo modprobe usbserial`

  `sudo insmod ./xr_usb_serial_common.ko`

After this when you do `ls /dev/tty*` you will see /dev/ttyXRUSB0. This means the driver is installed and you are in good shape.

Change the port in your code to '/dev/ttyXRUSB0'.

[See the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvsWg.png)

After you restart the PI you might not see the ttyXRUSB0 instead you will see ttyACM0. In such case execute `sudo echo blacklist cdc-acm > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cdc-acm.conf`. If PI does not allow you to execute then create the file in the path and write `blacklist cdc-acm`.

Reboot and verify if ttyACM0 is still displayed in `ls /dev/tty*`.

Comment: my problem has been solved. thank you for helping me in solving my problem :)