# cant read data from epever to raspberry

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspberry-pi to read data from epever by rs485 to usb.I'm using this PHP file to read data.

```
<?php
    /*
    * PHP EpSolar Tracer Class (PhpEpsolarTracer) v0.9
    *
    */

    //EPEver tracer php library
    require_once 'PhpEpsolarTracer.php';
    //influxDB php client library
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    //Define IP of influxDB
    $host = 'localhost';

    $tracer = new PhpEpsolarTracer('/dev/ttyUSBACM0');
    $client = new InfluxDB\Client($host,8086,"root","root");

    $db = $client->selectDB("logger");

    //'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'

    Print "\n Realtime Data\n";

    if ($tracer->getRealtimeData()) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($tracer->realtimeData); $i++) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8086/write?db=powerwall" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $Item = $tracer->realtimeData[$i];
            $Key_Name = str_replace(" ","-",$tracer->realtimeKey[$i]);
            Print str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . " " . $Key_Name . " " . $Item . "\n";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$Key_Name,unit=Realtime value=$Item" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
            $result = curl_exec ($ch);
        }
    } else 
        print "Cannot get RealTime Data\n";

    Print "\n Statistical Data\n";

    if ($tracer->getStatData()) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($tracer->statData); $i++) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8086/write?db=powerwall" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $Item = $tracer->statData[$i];
            $Key_Name = str_replace(" ","-",$tracer->statKey[$i]);
            $Key_Name = 'Stat-' . $Key_Name;
            Print str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . " " . $Key_Name . " " . $Item . "\n";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$Key_Name,unit=statData value=$Item" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
            $result = curl_exec ($ch);
        }
    } else 
        print "Cannot get Statistical Data\n";
?>
```

When I run this code I got the error message:

> Cannot get Real Time Data

So then I followed the issue in here:
[Modbus cant read data from epever tracer 1210a to raspberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313343/modbus-cant-read-data-from-epever-tracer-1210a-to-raspberry)

But I haven't do this, I got several errors.

Then I have checked the kernel version of my raspberry pi and it shows as

```
Linux raspberry pi 4.19.57-v7+ #1244 SMP Thu Jul 4 18:45:25 BST 2019   armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What USB to RS485 adaptor are you using? Have you tested it somewhere else? Are you sure your wiring is correct? And what abaout the identifier `/dev/ttyUSBACM0`, are you sure that's the right one?

Comment: when i type `lsusb` it shows like this `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e2:1411 Exar Corp`..I bought  USB to RS485 cable from epever and use it with their software successfully.

Comment: Reformatted code for readability

Comment: Those are good omens  Rahul, what happens when you type `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyU*`? Is the driver loaded?

Comment: I have followed the same way for my Kali Linux system and it succeeded but when i try with Raspian it fails to install the driver.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: `make -C /lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+ M=/home/pi/epsolar-tracer/xr_usb_serial_common-1a
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2` This is the error i got,